# Asymptotic expansion of $\int_0^{\pi/2} dx \sqrt{1-(1-\epsilon^2)\sin^2x}$ as $\epsilon\to 0$

Tags: asymptotics

I wish to find the asymptotic expansion of (at least the first few terms)
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\pi/2} dx \sqrt{1-(1-\epsilon^2)\sin^2x} 
\end{equation}
as $\epsilon\to 0$. This integral is closed related to the complete elliptic integral of the second kind, but I prefer not using any knowledge about that. I have no clue where to start.

The answer given by Mathematica is
\begin{equation}
1-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2\ln\epsilon+O(\epsilon^2)
\end{equation}

(PS: This is some integral I encountered while working on a problem of solid-state physics.)

Comment: @Yimin Hiccup: that Taylor expansion has a radius of convergence of $1$, but $\tan x$ is unbounded.

Comment: o, yes, that is why there is a log eps term then.

Comment: This is $E(k)$ with $k = \sqrt {1 - \epsilon ^2 }$, $k' = \epsilon$, see [$(19.12.2)$](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19.12.E2).

Comment: as @coiso mentioned, a direct expansion will not work, you need to truncate the integral to $(0, \frac{\pi}{2} - 2\epsilon)$ and the rest, the first integral then can be expanded in series, the second integral can be bounded by $\epsilon^2$.

Comment: Or use MMA code:`AsymptoticIntegrate[Sqrt[
  1 - (1 - \[Epsilon]^2)*Sin[x]^2], {x, 0, Pi/2}, {\[Epsilon], 0, 2}, 
  Assumptions -> \[Epsilon] > 0] // Expand` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Too long for a comment*

As was mentioned in the comment and the solution above, the systematic approach requires usage of the asymptotic of special functions. But it is always possible to find several first asymptotic terms directly.
$$I(\epsilon)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1-(1-\epsilon^2)\sin^2x}\,\,dx\overset{\tan x=t}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{1+\epsilon^2t^2}}{(1+t^2)^\frac32}dt$$
$$\overset{x=\frac1t}{=}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2}}{(1+x^2)^\frac32}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2}-x+x}{(1+x^2)^\frac32}dx$$
$$=\int_0^\infty\frac x{(1+x^2)^\frac32}dx+\epsilon^2\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^\frac32(x+\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2})}$$
$$\overset{x\to\epsilon x}{=}1+\epsilon^2\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2\epsilon^2)^\frac32(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})}$$
$$=1+\epsilon^2\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2\epsilon^2)^\frac32}\left(\frac1{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}-\frac1{2\sqrt{1+x^2}}+\frac1{2\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right)$$
$$\overset{x=\frac t\epsilon}{=}1+\frac{\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^\frac32\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2}}+\frac{\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^\frac32}\frac{\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2}-x}{\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2}(x+\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2})}$$
Making the substitution $x=\epsilon t$ in the last integral
$$=1+\frac{\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^\frac32\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2}}+\frac{\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{(1+t^2\epsilon^2)^\frac32\sqrt{1+t^2}(t+\sqrt{1+t^2}))^2}$$
We see that the last integral converges at $\epsilon=0$, so we drop $\epsilon$ inside the integral (i. e. dropping the terms $\sim\epsilon^4$). The first integral we integrate by part.
$$I(\epsilon)=1+\frac{\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}+\frac{\epsilon^2}2\frac{\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2})}{(1+x^2)^\frac32}\,\bigg|_{x=0}^\infty+$$
$$+\frac{3\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac{x\,\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+\epsilon^2})}{(1+x^2)^\frac52}dx+O(\epsilon^4)$$
The last integral converges at $\epsilon=0$. Dropping $\epsilon$ inside the integral (dropping the terms $\sim\epsilon^4\ln\epsilon$)
$$I(\epsilon)=1-\frac{\epsilon^2}2\ln\epsilon+\frac{\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}+\frac{3\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac {x\,\ln(2x)}{(1+x^2)^\frac52}dx+O(\epsilon^4\ln\epsilon)$$
Using the substitution $x=\sinh t$ in the first integral
$$\frac{\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1+x^2}(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}=\frac{\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{e^{2t}}=\frac{\epsilon^2}4$$
The last integral
$$\frac{3\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac {x\,\ln(2x)}{(1+x^2)^\frac52}dx=\frac{3\ln2\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac{t\,dt}{(1+t^2)^\frac52}+\frac{3\epsilon^2}2\int_0^\infty\frac{t\,\ln t}{(1+t^2)^\frac52}dt$$
$$=\frac{\ln 2}2\epsilon^2+\frac{\ln2-1}2\epsilon^2=\left(\ln2-\frac12\right)\,\epsilon^2$$
Taking all together,
$$I(\epsilon)=1-\frac{\epsilon^2\,\ln\epsilon}2+\left(\ln2-\frac14\right)\epsilon^2+O(\epsilon^4\ln\epsilon)$$
Numeric evaluation (WA) confirms the answer.

Comment: This is immensely helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As said in comments, using Mathematica notation,

$$I=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \sqrt{1-(1-\epsilon^2)\sin^2(x)}\,dx= E\left(1-\epsilon ^2\right)$$

Just type

`Series[EllipticE[1-\[Epsilon]^2],{\[Epsilon],0,7}, Assumptions -> \[Epsilon] > 0]`

and simplify (changing the $7$ to whatever will give more and more terms).